# How to call correctly methods from a model relating to other controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, model, controller

In my Ruby on Rails application I want to create a new profile and a new statistic for profile, all calling first the related method from the user model, and then from the profile model.

So...

... in my user model (user.rb) I have this:

```
...

has_one :profile

...
before_save :inizialize_user
...

private

def inizialize_user
  @user_profile = Profile.new
  self.user_profile_id = @user_profile.id
end
```

... in my profile model (profiles.rb) I have this:

```
...
belongs_to :user
...

before_save :inizialize_profile

private

def inizialize_profile
  @profile_statistic = ProfileStatistic.new
end
```

In the second block of code, on the "before_save" it instantiates a new profile statistic:
"inspecting" @profile_statistic results a new object (correct!)

In the first block of code, on the "before_save" it doesn't instantiate a new profile:
"inspecting" the @user_profile results nil (it must be a new profile object!)

The last part is my problem. Why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Profile.new`, it only creates an instance in memory, it isn't saved to the database and therefore doesn't have an `id` attribute (i.e. @user_profile.id is nil).

I suggest you replace

```
@user_profile = Profile.new
```

with

```
@user_profile = Profile.create
```

`create` will save the instance and then @user_profile.id will not be nil.

You probably also wan to use `before_create` callbacks (not `before_save`), or you'll have new user profiles every time you save the model (e.g. after udpating). Also, you probably want to have

```
ProfileStatistic.create
```

instead of

```
ProfileStatistic.new
```

Comment: I don't understand why "ProfileStatistic.create" doesn't work: it seems do not create a new Profile object.

Comment: ProfileStatistic.create will save the record to the database. So if you have validations that fail, it will not work. For example, if you have a "validates_presence_of :name", you can create it like this ProfileStatistic.create(:name => 'the name you want'). Make sure you create a profile statistic with all validations passing. You can test it in the console with "p = ProfileStatistic.create". If the console returns 'false', see why with "p.errors"